# AngularJS ng-options get selected item as an object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-ng-model

I have an object array in my scope and I list them in a dropdown control like below.

```
 <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="product.ID as product.Name for product in products">
     <option value="">Please select a product...</option>
 </select>
```

I also want to get the selectedItem as an object to reach other attributes of the object so I can manupulate the content in my page. For example;

```
<a ng-show="selectedItem.isAvailable">Buy Now!</a>
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to remove `select as` part from the ng-options, so that the selected `product` will be the ngModel, `selectedItem`.

Try:-

```
 <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="product.Name for product in products track by product.id">
     <option value="">Please select a product...</option>
 </select>
```

Your current syntax is `select as label for value in array` where `select` is the `product.ID`, so you would just change it to `label for value in array`

Comment: But its not default selected when i use the track by and selected in the case of as, because I am storing only the id (reference) in collection. So there is any solution for it?

Comment: tks.. u save me